# Unable to burn blank dvd

Tags: mount, 16.04, dvd, burning, k3b

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

I am using k3b as my default dvd burner

When I insert any blank dvd I get the following error:

unable to mount DVD-R Disc location is already mounted

I tried with DVD which already has data

I got the same error

But using nautilus I could access the files

In the same way when I inserted blank DVD k3b correctly detected it and showed all the details.

I tried to burn an ISO. After starting in a smooth way after about a minute it gave me error message: Writing error. My DVD also got corrupted.

It gave the following error report:

```
Burned media
-----------------------
DVD+R

Devices
-----------------------
HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GUA0N AL00 (/dev/sr0, CD-R, CD-RW, CD-ROM, DVD-ROM, DVD-R, DVD-RW, DVD-R DL, DVD+R, DVD+RW, DVD+R DL) [DVD-ROM, DVD-R Sequential, DVD-R Dual Layer Sequential, DVD-R Dual Layer Jump, DVD-RAM, DVD-RW Restricted Overwrite, DVD-RW Sequential, DVD+RW, DVD+R, DVD+R Dual Layer, CD-ROM, CD-R, CD-RW] [SAO, TAO, RAW, SAO/R96P, SAO/R96R, RAW/R16, RAW/R96P, RAW/R96R, Restricted Overwrite, Layer Jump] [%7]

System
-----------------------
K3b Version: 2.0.3
KDE Version: 4.14.16
QT Version:  4.8.7
Kernel:      4.4.0-23-generic

Used versions
-----------------------
growisofs: 7.1

growisofs
-----------------------
Executing 'builtin_dd if=/dev/fd/0 of=/dev/sr0 obs=32k seek=0'
/dev/sr0: "Current Write Speed" is 8.2x1352KBps.
          0/3842639872 ( 0.0%) @0x, remaining ??:?? RBU 100.0% UBU   0.0%
=== last message repeated 7 times. ===
:-[ WRITE@LBA=0h failed with SK=3h/POWER CALIBRATION AREA ERROR]: Input/output error
:-( write failed: Input/output error

growisofs command:
-----------------------
/usr/bin/growisofs -Z /dev/sr0=/dev/fd/0 -use-the-force-luke=notray -use-the-force-luke=tty -use-the-force-luke=4gms -use-the-force-luke=tracksize:1876289 -use-the-force-luke=dao:1876289 -dvd-compat -speed=8 -use-the-force-luke=bufsize:32m
```

What to do now?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have been able to find the cause of the problem.

My laptop model is Lenovo B50. Its ethernet card is r8168. However lenovo provides drivers for r8168 for Ubuntu which works only upto Ubuntu 12.04 and I have Ubuntu 16.04. As such not only my dvd drive but also ether port is not working, quite frustrating. Now my only option is to use external usb dvd drive and wifi internet.

Comment: might be also a good idea to replace cdrkit with cdrtools